# Up and down image view and vice versa Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For my personal project, I try to make an image of a leaf go up for 5 seconds and then lower it for 5 seconds.
It works well, only after raising and lowering the sheet, it changes position and is transported well to the bottom of the screen.
I would like it to go up from the place of the end of the descent. I have tried several things but nothing works. I wish I could restore the original position after descent but I think it will make the image flicker on the screen.
Any ideas ?

```
func upLeaf(){
        let xPosition = imageLeaf.frame.origin.x
        let yPosition = imageLeaf.frame.origin.y - 100 // Slide Up - 20px
        let width = imageLeaf.frame.size.width
        let height = imageLeaf.frame.size.height
      
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
            self.imageLeaf.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: width, height: height)
        })
    }
    
    func downLeaf(){
        let xPosition = imageLeaf.frame.origin.x
        let yPosition = imageLeaf.frame.origin.y + 100 // Slide Up - 20px
        
        let width = imageLeaf.frame.size.width
        let height = imageLeaf.frame.size.height
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
            self.imageLeaf.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: width, height: height)
        })
        secondUp = true
    }
```

Comment: Show a little more code... are you using constraints for the initial size / position of the image view? Are you calling `upLeaf()` / `downLeaf()` on button taps? Or on a timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using frame to perform the animation you could use CGAffineTransform. It's more powerful and equally easy:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
   line3.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 100)
})
```

When you want to return to the initial state you should type:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
    line3.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
})
```

`CGAffineTransform` remembers the initial parameters for your view, so that you don't have to do any calculations yourself.

Comment: This works, but it has limitations. When you've changed a view's transform to something other than identity the frame property is no longer valid. Also, if the user needs to be able to interact with the view (tap on it, etc) then it will detect taps/drags as if it had not been moved. (That last point probably doesn't apply here but is worth mentioning.)

Comment: Andre3000: Thank you very much that solved my problem, many thanks! It's awesome !! :D
 Duncan C: Thanks also for your information, I don't need user interactions for this project but I take note in case of problems;).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the leaf to go up and down, you can just animate `imageLeaf`'s `frame.origin.y` (no need to keep track of `origin.x`, `width`, or `height`).

```
func upDownLeaf() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
            self.imageLeaf.frame.origin.y -= 100 /// go up
    }) { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
            self.imageLeaf.frame.origin.y += 100 /// go down
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tried but it caused the same teleport down issue. But thank you anyway because I solved my problem. Many thanks !! : D